# Java Help, error message "file not found"

Tags: java

I'm trying to run this code that was supposed to be a cut and paste easy assignment from my teacher. However, after following the instructions I still get this error message:

> "The specified file, ShapeData.txt was not found."

which refers back to line 30.

I did cut and paste the file into the same folder as all the rest, so i'm not sure why I'm still getting the error. I also read about doing something in the command line, but not sure what it is I'm suppose to do.

(Oh, and this is *not* a homework assignment or anything that I can turn in for a grade. It is just something we can look at to get a better understanding.)

Here is my code, or at least the first couple of line anyway.

```
/**
 * Concepts demonstrated:
 *  Object Inheritance
 *  Interfaces
 *  Interface Implementation
 *  Reading Data from a File
 *  Sorting an Array
 *  Manipulating Strings 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
     * This lab demonstrates the basics of object-oriented programming.
     */
    public class Lab8 {

        private static Shape[] shapes; // An array to hold all the shape objects

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DataReader reader = new DataReader("ShapeData.txt");// The reader is used to read data from a file


            // Display program information
            System.out.println("Ima Java Programmer");
            System.out.println("Shape Info");

            // Load data from the file
            if(reader.loadData("ShapeData.txt")) { // The filename is entered using a command-line argument
                shapes = reader.getShapeData(); // Store the arrays in the array

                // Display how many shapes were read from the file
                System.out.println("Successfully loaded " + shapes[0].getCount() + 
                                   " shapes from the selected data file!");
                displayMenu();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShapeData.txt file must be in your working directory` ,because here you not specified full path. working directory  may be your java bin directory

Comment: This is simply incorrect. Placing the file in the (I assume you mean Java) bin directory does not make it available to be loaded when a full path is not specified.

Comment: Yes, the file would need to be in the working directory for the Java process, not a bin directory.

Comment: thanks, i used a little from everyone and figured it out, thanks i had to move the ShapeData.txt file out of my class file, wow

Answer (score 3):

```
new DataReader("ShapeData.txt");
```

You need to provide full path of ShapeData.txt (assuming ShapeData.txt is not in working directory of the Java process).

Comment: I will upvote if you correct `assuming ShapeData.txt is not in the same folder as your class file).`. The file would need to be in the working directory of the Java process, whatever that may be (will be different depending on how the JVM was launched).

Comment: @Perception: Make sense, Changed words.

Comment: thanks, i used a little from everyone and figured it out, thanks i had to move the ShapeData.txt file out of my class file, wow

Answer (score 0):

You could add the file's path in your ant build file to copy it in your working directory via:

```
<copy todir="/path/to/copy" overwrite="false">
    <fileset dir="/source/path" />
</copy>
```

Or try using:

```
File file = new File("filename");
DataReader reader = new DataReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
```